# How to compose GridView image list from specific folder

Tags: android, adapter, android-gridview, android-sdcard

I have used `GridView` where i can display my images in rows and columns. But in this case, almost every image in Gallery appears on the table. I want images from a specific folder such as `sdcard/Images/aaa.jpg`. Can you please suggest me how can i do it on my code below? Thank you.

This is Activity Class:

```
public class CardBox extends Activity {

private Cursor cursor;
private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cardbox);

String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

cursor = getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);


columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Context context;

            public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
                context = localContext;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return cursor.getCount();
            }
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView picturesView;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    picturesView = new ImageView(context);
                    // Move cursor to current position
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    // Get the current value for the requested column
                    int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                    // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
                    picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ imageID));

                    picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                    picturesView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
                    picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                }
                else {
                    picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
                }
                return picturesView;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the required folders, You can iterate over the folders first from which you need images and store path in Collection and use that list in adapter to populate the data.

Comment: yea this is the method can apply but what is the syntax for it and where i need to apply i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Query this way

```
private String[] arrPath;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private int ids[];
    private int count;

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, new String[] {"%myimagesfolder%"}, orderBy); //UPDATE HERE

    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    count = imagecursor.getCount();
    arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
```

Comment: i have tried. Activity stops. and logCat is about SqliteException. i dont think its relevant. can you configure this with my code above to demonstrate please?